# how do i solve "only static members can be accessed in initializers " error

Tags: flutter

[trying to pass the id to a static function fetchByid](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lwjtV.png)

please am unable to access the final id value, is there a way to access the value, this is the code
please am unable to access the final id value, is there a way to access the value, this is the code
`

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:learning_system/models/restaurant.dart';
import '../../models/restaurant_page_header.dart';

class RestaurantScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  final int id;
  RestaurantScreen(this.id);
  // Restaurant rest = Restaurant.fetchById(id);

  @override
  _RestaurantScreenState createState() => _RestaurantScreenState();
}

class _RestaurantScreenState extends State<RestaurantScreen> {
  Restaurant rest = Restaurant.fetchById(widget.id);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: CustomScrollView(
        slivers: <Widget>[
          SliverPersistentHeader(
            pinned: true,
            delegate: RestaurantPageHeader(
                maxExtent: 270.0, minExtent: 85.0, rest: rest),
          ),
          SliverList(
            delegate: SliverChildBuilderDelegate(
              (context, index) => ListTile(
                
                title: Text(rest.menu[index].foodName),
                subtitle: Text(rest.menu[index].supliments),
                trailing: Image.asset(rest.restImageUrl)
              ),
              childCount: rest.menu.length
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

`

Comment: Please don't provide your code in image format. Can you provide it in the text version?

Answer (score 0):

You can execute `rest = Restaurant.fetchBy(widget.id);` in `initState()` 
code snippet

```
class RestaurantScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  final int id;

  RestaurantScreen(this.id);
  @override
  _RestaurantScreenState createState() => _RestaurantScreenState();
}

class _RestaurantScreenState extends State<RestaurantScreen> {
  Restaurant rest;

  @override
  void initState() {
    rest = Restaurant.fetchBy(widget.id);
    super.initState();
  }
```